# Plotting the intersection of multiple surfaces with WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, visualization, wolfram-alpha

I want to plot the intersection of two surfaces like in this [post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/123570).

But if I enter the much simplified expression

> ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4=0, xy=1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

he gives me an error message, you can try it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot3D%5B%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20-%204%3D0%2C%20xy%3D1%7D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20-2%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%20-2%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7Bz%2C%20-2%2C%202%7D%5D), so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because it works in Mathematica, doesn't mean it'll work in Wolfram|Alpha. From the [FAQ](http://www.wolframalpha.com/faqs7.html):

> **Can I use Mathematica code in Wolfram|Alpha?**
>
> Yes. **Most** small pieces of Mathematica code will work in Wolfram|Alpha. In most cases, you can mix the Mathematica code with pseudocode and math.

If you have access to Mathematica, you need to use `==` instead of `=`, and you also need to use `x*y` else Mathematica will treat `xy` as its own variable.

[image: ContourPlot3D]